# Finding the Fastest Possible Race Strategy with Multiple Pit Stops and Tire Compounds in C#

Tags: c#, function, loops, sum

I am attempting to write a script to determine the shortest possible time for a 40-lap race by considering combinations of tyre compounds and pit stops (how many laps between each pit stop). The number of laps in between each pit stop is referred to as a segment.

Currently, my script brute forces all possible combinations (segments could be no bigger than 25 laps, so there are only 20 proper combinations of segments and tyre compounds) for a one pitstop strategy, but the way I implemented it becomes impractical to write when moving to three segments (two pit stop) strategies.

Is there a more efficient way to generate and run through all of possible race strategies, considering different tyre compounds and lap segments? Simply put, I'm looking to see if I can I automate the generation of race strategies instead of manually having to list them?

Here is the current script so far (using decimal instead of double as it's for a math paper):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<decimal> findMin = new List<decimal>();

        //Add all possible values to the list 
        for(int i = 25; i >= 20; i--)
        {
            findMin.Add(LowestCombo(i, 40 - i));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        //Print lowest number in the list
        Console.WriteLine($"The lowest possible time achievable is {findMin.Min()}");

    }
    public static decimal LowestCombo (int a, int b){
        List<decimal> sumBoth = new List<decimal>();
        string[] identifier = {"all soft tyres", "all medium tyres", "soft, then medium", "medium, then soft"};

        //Add all possible combinations of the two to the list
        sumBoth.Add(SoftSummation(a) + SoftSummation(b));
        sumBoth.Add(MedSummation(a) + MedSummation(b));
        sumBoth.Add(SoftSummation(a) + MedSummation(b));
        sumBoth.Add(MedSummation(a) + SoftSummation(b));
        
        //Print the combination of laps and tyres as well as the time, then return the lowest time
        Console.WriteLine($"The lowest possible time achievable with {a} initial laps and {b} final laps for a 1 pit stop race is {sumBoth.Min()}, {identifier[sumBoth.IndexOf(sumBoth.Min())]}.");
        return sumBoth.Min();
    }

    
    public static decimal SoftSummation(int a)
    {   
        decimal sum = 0;
        
            for(int x = 1; x <= a; x++)
            {
                //Tyre degradation function for the soft compound (Math.Pow can't take decimal??)
                sum += (0.1262m * (x * x * x * x)) - (4.476m * (x * x * x)) + (56.37m * (x * x)) - (152.9m * x) + (1.427m * (100000m));
            }
        
        return sum; 
    }

    
    public static decimal MedSummation(int a)
    {   
        decimal sum = 0;
        
            for(int x = 1; x <= a; x++)
            {
                //Tyre degradation function for the medium compound
                sum += (0.8406m * (x * x)) + (44.77m * x) + (1.434m * 100000m);
            }
        
        return sum; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What are `a` & `b`? What do they relate to?

Comment: You can quarter the processing time simply by `SoftSummation(a)` and `MedSummation(b)` only once each.

Comment: @YungDeiza a and b are the two segments, a being before the pit and b after.